# Could i use <a> in <ul> around <li>

Tags: html, validation

Ive got the following code:

```
<ul> 
     <a href="./index.php?profile=User1">
        <li>User1 : 16</li>
     </a>
     <a href="./index.php?profile=User2">
        <li>User2 : 4</li>
    </a>
</ul>
```

This works perfectly fine in all major browsers, but it isn't allowed/invalid HTML and the right way should be this:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
        <a href="./index.php?profile=User1">User1 : 16</a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a href="./index.php?profile=User2">User2 : 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But if I do it like the second example only the text not the whole `<li>` is clickable like i want it to.

Should I stay with the invalid working version or has anyone a better solution?

Comment: Example with [JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/bGBAu/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use CSS to make the link take up the entire list item, eg. `display: block` (and any other styling you might want).

Wrapping links around list items is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is **NO**, it won't be validated, only `li` can be inside `ul` and `ol` elements.

So this is incorrect

```
<ul>
  <a><li></li></a>
</ul>
```

This is fine

```
<ul>
  <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Anchor tag is inline element so make it block using **display:'block'** so that it will take full width of its parent i.e. li tag

Answer (score 0):

The second way around is the correct way to do it, you just have some minor styling issues.

If you set the `<li>`'s to have no padding and the `<a>`'s to have no margin, the links will fill the entire area of the list item.

Comment: Not true. `a` is an inline element by default and will have only the width of its children.

Comment: `<li>`s also have inline behavior (although they're inline-blocks), so they'll take up the space of the `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the valid way.

And set the "a" tag with :

```
display: block
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TYVV6/1/

And if you don't want to show the points at the beggining of the list elements.

You'll have to use :

```
list-style: none;
```